# Reassigning values from multilevel array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, frontend

I have got an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "pageId": "1",
    "menuPos": "Parent",
    "mainPageId": "1",
    "subMenu": [
      {
        "pageId": "1",
        "menuPos": "Parent and child",
        "mainPageId": "1",
        "subMenu": [
          {
            "pageId": "67",
            "menuPos": "Child",
            "mainPageId": "67"
          },
          {
            "pageId": "68",
            "menuPos": "Child and paren",
            "mainPageId": "68",
            "subMenu": [
              {
                "pageId": "70",
                "menuPos": "Child",
                "mainPageId": "70"
              },
              {
                "pageId": "69",
                "menuPos": "Child",
                "mainPageId": "69"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks to tymeJV from stackoverlow now i know how to iterate trough this array, but i still working on how to reassign values from array to another array. I made a recursive function for this, but in output i still have the same values. Here is the code.

currentData = event.dest.nodesScope.$treeScope.data;

```
    var outputData = [];

    function iterateMenus(menu) {

        if(menu.length > 0) {
        outputData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
            console.log(menu[i].pageId+" "+menu[i].menuPos);
            outputData[i] = {
                menuPos: menu[i].menuPos,
                pageId: menu[i].pageId,
                subMenu: [ iterateMenus(menu[i].subMenu) ]
                }
            }
        }
        return outputData;
    }

    var output = iterateMenus(currentData);
```

In output a i want to display only pageId, menuPos and subMenu if exists. I also want to add parentId if it is possible( i am sure it is )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) only the value you want the object array to handle

```
function iterateMenus(menus) {
    var outputData = [];
    if (menus && menus.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
            var menu = menus[i];
            console.log(menu.pageId + " " + menu.menuPos);
            //check if exist
            if (menu.pageId || menu.menuPos || menu.subMenu) {
                var object = {
                    menuPos: menu.menuPos,
                    pageId: menu.pageId,
                    subMenu: [iterateMenus(menu.subMenu)]
                };
                outputData.push(object);
            }
        }
    }
    return outputData;
}
```

Comment: It is working! I couldn't sleep all night because of this issue. I'm a javascript moron :( Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

With @yesterdaysfoe i made the function i want. I also add a parentId parameter and now it looks like this:

```
currentData = event.dest.nodesScope.$treeScope.data;
            var outputData = [];

            function iterateMenus(menus, parent) {
                var outputData = [];
                if (menus && menus.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
                        var menu = menus[i];
                        console.log(menu.pageId + " " + menu.menuPos);
                        //check if exist
                        if (menu.pageId || menu.menuPos || menu.subMenu) {
                            var object = {
                                menuPos: menu.menuPos,
                                pageId: menu.pageId,
                                newOrder: i,
                                parentId: parent,
                                subMenu: [iterateMenus(menu.subMenu, menu.pageId)]
                            };
                            outputData.push(object);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return outputData;
            }

            var output = iterateMenus(currentData);
```